# Calculate high power of matrix in an efficient way.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

**My Question**

> Assume $A=\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{bmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{bmatrix}-1&1&2\end{bmatrix}$, and $C=AB$. Find $C$ and $C^{100}$.

**My Attempt**

I have no problem calculating $C$, but for $C^{100}$ I am stuck. I have tried calculating $$C^2=\begin{bmatrix}-7&7&14\\-14&14&28\\-21&21&42\end{bmatrix}, $$ and $$C^4=\begin{bmatrix}-343&343&686\\-686&686&1372\\-1029&1029&2058\end{bmatrix}.$$

I noticed the only difference between the first and second column is the opposite sign, and the third column is always twice the second. From another point of view, the second row is always twice the first, and the third row is three times the first.

I think the trick lies in how I interpret the matrix multiplication $C=AB$, or interpret $A$ and $B$ in some other way. However I cannot figure it out, which is why I come here for help. Thanks for reading my post.

Comment: Just write $C = AB$ and group the terms in a different way in $C^{100}$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest method is probably to note that
$$ C^{100} = (AB)^{100} = A (BA)^{99} B$$
and that $BA$ is particularly easy to compute and exponentiate.

---

A different method (certainly suboptimal here but frequently very useful) is to use repeated squaring. Namely, to compute $C^{100}$ you compute
$$ C, C^2, C^4, C^8, C^{16}, C^{32}, C^{64}, $$
(each of which is the square of the previous, so this is rapidly computable), and then compute
$$ C^{100} = C^{64} C^{32} C^4 C^2. $$
In total this would take $10$ matrix multiplications, which is pretty efficient.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for help.

Comment: The command of Mathematica

    `MatrixPower[(KroneckerProduct[{1, 2, 3}, {-1, 1, 2}]), 100] // MatrixForm` produces

Comment: `{{-4620680728035368559063782527286024015510290284149464858476993330559\
55922805275437143, 
  46206807280353685590637825272860240155102902841494648584769933305595\
5922805275437143, 
  92413614560707371181275650545720480310205805682989297169539866611191\
1845610550874286}, \
{-92413614560707371181275650545720480310205805682989297169539866611191\
1845610550874286,...}}`

Answer (score -1):

Rather than multiplying $C\cdot C \cdot \ldots \cdot C$, consider

$$ C^{100} = (AB)^{100} = (AB)(AB)\cdot (AB)$$

Is there another way you can write this last product?

> Consider $A(BA)(BA)\cdot (BA)B$. Why might this be easier?